# How to fill input textfield using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**EDIT**
There was a bug in Firefor driver. It was solved by using chrome driver.

[image]I am new to python and I am developing a script that will send message on whatsapp using webwhatsapp.
But I am not able to write anything in text inputfeild using driver.send_key('message') method.

```
<input type="text" class="input input-search" data-tab="2" dir="auto" spellcheck="false" title="Search or start new chat" value="">
```

CODE

```
contactSearch=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Search or start new chat"]').click()
contactSearch.send_keys("name")
```

I have tried contactSearch.clear() and click() method also but the input remains blank.the code is from https://web.whatsapp.com/ go there login and there will be a feild called Search or start new chat.I want to input text in that field.

Answer (score 1):

**You are not logged in** to whatsapp in your selenium session and hence there is no "New chat" button. By default, selenium starts a brand new browser session with default preferences, no browser history or cookies.

Comment: @alexce I can manuallu login and New chat button feature works just fine.The problem is where when I try to enter anything in input field it remains blank. driver.send_key('message') won't enter message in input field.. thanks.

Comment: @Priyamvaidya yeah, but you do it manually. You have to mimic the logging  logic in your Python/Selenium code as well.

Comment: I have updated the question. It would be great if you take another look. thanks