# How to write something inside <div> element using python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Edit**
The problem can be solved using sned_keys() method of selenium driver.

I am developing a webwhatsapp spamming script and I want to  do the following:

```
<div class="input" contenteditable="true" data-tab="1" dir="auto" spellcheck="true"></div>
```

The things what we write between  tag goes as input to whatsapp "send message" function.

I want to do

```
<div class="input" contenteditable="true" data-tab="1" dir="auto" spellcheck="true">ABC</div>
```

How can I do that? I am new to python.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest go with some basic approach like,

String splitting/concat/using regex patterns.
It may give you some basic idea of parsing strings etc..

Looking at your requirement, You may go for DOM/XML parsing modules like element tree/beautiful soap etc

Here is example with BeautifulSoup,

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup('<div class="input" contenteditable="true" data-tab="1" dir="auto" spellcheck="true">ABC</div>')
>>> t = soup.find('div')
>>> t
<div class="input" contenteditable="true" data-tab="1" dir="auto" spellcheck="true">ABC</div>
>>> t.string = "PQR"
>>> t
<div class="input" contenteditable="true" data-tab="1" dir="auto" spellcheck="true">PQR</div>
>>>
>>> str(t)
'<div class="input" contenteditable="true" data-tab="1" dir="auto" spellcheck="true">PQR</div>'
>>>
```

Comment: It didin't work. Here's what is I'm trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409737/how-to-fill-input-textfield-using-python

Comment: It worked using send_keys method of selenium driver. i was using wrong element to finf it. thanx by the way.

Answer (score 0):

@Priyam Normally everyone do it using String Interpolation try it

Comment: ,I am new to python.can you provide an simple code using above example.I want to enter ABC inside <div></div> tag.Thanx